# Java double incorrect cast to int

Tags: java, casting

When i try cast double to int. My variable "check" is always equals zero. But if i do it in psvm it works. If i do it in class check is always equals zero. How can i fix this problem? I try use Double and Integer for cast it doesn't work too.

I use java 11 on Ubuntu 18.

```
public class Round {

    public int round (double value) {
        return (value > 0) ? roundPositiveNubmer(value) : roundNegativeNumber(value);
    }

    private int roundPositiveNubmer(double value) {
        int result;
        double checkD = value * 10 % 10;
        int check = (int) checkD;
        if (check > 5) {
            value++;
            result = (int) value;
        } else {
            result = (int) value;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int roundNegativeNumber(double value) {
        int result;
        double checkD = value * 10 % 10;
        int check = (int) checkD;
        if (check > -5 && check < 0) {
            value--;
            result =  (int) value;
        } else {
            result =  (int) value;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

When i try to round 23.6. I've got 23 but must 24.

Comment: Have you tried Math.round() ? Does it not work for you?

Comment: I have added `public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Round().round(23.6));
    }` to your class, compiled and ran it, and it gave 24. So, what's the actual problem?

Comment: The behaviour of cast is dictated by JLS 5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion, and the behaviour you describe conforms to that definition (_"[..] if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). [..]"_. In other words, the cast is not 'incorrect', but your expectation is.

Comment: I need to wtrire custom class for rounding of number. I got problem with.
int check = (int) value * 10 % 10;
This string doesnt work in class method but work in psvm.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works nicely in the positive case, as JB Nizet already hinted in a comment.

The trouble is with the negative case. `round(-23.6)` yields -23, not -24. It is caused by this line:

```
    if (check > -5 && check < 0) {
```

In the -23.6 case `check` is -6, which is *less* than -5. I think you want the simpler:

```
    if (check < -5) {
```

Now -23.6 is rounded to -24. -23.5 is still rounded to -23. If you wanted -24 in this case too:

```
    if (check <= -5) {
```

You may also want to consider whether you wanted `>=` in the positive case.

### Or just use Math.round()

Sourabh Bhat is right in the comment too: You are reinventing the wheel. `Math.round()` already does the job that your rounding method is doing. So if you are coding this as an exercise, fine, you’re learning, that’s always good. For production code you should prefer to use the existing built-in library method instead.

```
    int rounded = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(-23.6));
    System.out.println("Rounded: " + rounded);
```

> Rounded: -24

Comment: I need to wtrire custom class for rounding of number. I got problem with.
int check = (int) value * 10 % 10;
This string doesnt work in class method but work in psvm.

Comment: I cannot reproduce “doesn’t work” in my Eclipse. Are you saying that you pass 23.6 to the method and `check` gets equal to 0 in the cast? What is the value of `checkD` in your debugger or if you print it? (I don’t know what PSVM is.)